# how to use command to convert modulus and exponent to RSA public key

Tags: windows, openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have a RSAKeyValue Modulus and Exponent, and I'd like to get public key based on them, I saw there are some answers using python library, while I can't use python in my project, I was wondering is it possible to use windows commands (no bash) or openssl to do this? thanks!

`<RSAKeyValue>              <Modulus>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</Modulus> <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent> </RSAKeyValue>`

Comment: That is the XMLsec representation of an RSA public key. You apparently want some other representation, but there are dozens commonly used and probably thousands possible -- which one do you want?